# Soot - Map from java class to jimple

Tags: java, static-analysis, code-analysis, soot, internal-representation

With the following code I can get the `jimple` representation of a java `.class` file:

```java
        soot.Main.main(args);
        SootClass mainClass = Scene.v().getMainClass();
        String methodSignature = "void main(java.lang.String[])";
        SootMethod mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod(methodSignature);
        Body jimpleBody = mainMethod.retrieveActiveBody();
```

However, I need to know the map from `.class` to `jimple`. In detail, For a certain line of code in the `.class` file, I want to know its corresponding `jimple` representation. Since one line of code can be converted into multiple `jimple` codes, this map can be one-to-many. Does there exist any API or method that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302540/how-can-we-obtain-the-original-source-line-number-of-a-unit-from-an-apk-in-soot). In detail, for a `Unit` you can use

```java
Unit unit = ...
int sourceID = unit.getJavaSourceStartLineNumber();
// do something smart here ...
```